# How to iterate over a numpy array, getting two values per loop?

Tags: python, numpy, loops

I envision something like

```
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(10)
for i, j in x:
     print(i,j)
```

and get something like

```
0 1
2 3
4 5
6 7
8 9
```

But I get this traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/andreas/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/PyCharm-P/ch-0/223.8214.51/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevconsole.py", line 364, in runcode
    coro = func()
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable numpy.int64 object
```

I also tried to use `np.nditer(x)` and `itertools` with `zip(x[::2], x[1::2])`, but that does not work either, with different error messages.

This should be super simple, but I can't find solutions online.

Comment: What is the purpose of the iteration?  There is likely a more efficient (numpy-esque) approach.

Answer (score 4):

You were trying to put `0` into `i` and `j` which is not possible.
To achieve that result you'll have to reshape your numpy array using either `x = x.reshape((5,2))` or `x.shape = 5, 2`. Then you can unpack it like that.

To visualize, this is what your current code is doing:

```py
i, j = 0
...
i, j = 1
...
```

And this is what will happen if you reshape it:

```py
i, j = [0, 1]
...
i, j = [2, 3]
...
```

Edit:

```py
import numpy as np
N = 10

x = np.arange(N).reshape((N/2, 2))
for i, j in x:
     print(i,j)
```

Comment: oh, i understand, thank you for explaining it in simple terms!

Comment: your solution is best so far. if you would please provide a snippet, so i can accept your answer. @wingedseal

Comment: I'm on mobile and won't be able to access my laptop for quite a while

Comment: I coded my solution based on your suggestion and am in no hurry. Just do it later.

Answer (score 0):

Is it what you want?

```
for x in range(0,10,2):
    print(x, x+1)
```

or your values are maintained in the numpy array x, then

```
for i in range(0, len(x), 2):
    print(x[i],x[i+1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying to be faithful to the original attempt. `zip`ping tuples of pairs of even and odds:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(10)

for i, j in zip(x[::2], x[1::2]):
     print(i,j)
```

Comment: Does that run for you? I tried that (as mentioned) and got an error.

Comment: yes, running `numpy 1.23`, test it also [here](https://onecompiler.com/python/3yuvmxayb)